# How can I avoid the output "0 tries left"?

Tags: python

My program asks the user to input how many tries/attempts they would like for answering each question. When the user runs out of tries, my program prints "0 tries left." How can I prevent this so that my program only prints "You are out of tries"?

Here is the specific function of my code:

```
def test_student(max_attempts, prob_spec, prob_sol):
    counter = 0
    print("The problem is:", prob_spec)
    while counter < max_attempts:
         user_answer = int(input("\t Your answer:")) 
         if user_answer != int(prob_sol):
              counter = counter + 1
              print("Try again. You have", (max_attempts - counter), "tries left.")
         elif user_answer == int(prob_sol):
              print("Correct!")
              return True
              break
    if counter == max_attempts:
         print("You are out of tries. The answer was:", prob_sol)
         return False
```

Comment: `while counter < max_attempts - 1`

Comment: @JohnGordon that won't work. Rethink it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redesigned your code a little:

```
def test_student(max_attempts, prob_spec, prob_sol):
    counter = 0
    print("The problem is:", prob_spec)
    while True:
         user_answer = int(input("\t Your answer:")) 
         if user_answer == int(prob_sol):
            print("Correct!")
            return True

        counter += 1

        if counter == max_attempts:
            print("You are out of tries. The answer was:", prob_sol)
            return False

        print("Try again. You have", (max_attempts - counter), "tries left.")
```

1. No need for `break` after a `return`.
2. No need to check equality and then immediately inequality, it's superfluous.
3. Try exiting a while loop as soon as possible if you're correct, it leads to more readable code.
4. As you can see, instead of checking the counter as the while condition, I check it later on. This allows you to take care of the last attempt differently.

Keep in mind you can use the max_attempts as a counter by running `max_attempts -= 1` and comparing the result to 0. I chose to go with your way as it's completely reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
print("Try again. You have", (max_attempts - counter), "tries left.")
```

to this:

```
if max_attempts - counter != 0:
   print("Try again. You have", (max_attempts - counter), "tries left.")
else:
   break
```

Comment: You don't need a semicolon in python

Comment: Oop, sorry. I forgot.